# Typescript namespace inside module - how to reference it?

Tags: typescript

The type definition for the [ngstorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) library is as follows:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

declare module 'angular' {
  export namespace storage {

    export interface IStorageService {
      //interface definition
    }

    export interface IStorageProvider extends angular.IServiceProvider {
      //interface definition
    }
  }
}
```

Three questions:

1. What exactly happens when the already-existing module 'angular' is declared again, as happens on line 3 of this example?
2. What does it mean to export a namespace inside a module definition `export namespace storage`?
3. How do I import `IStorageService` into my `.ts` files? Nothing I've tried so far works.

   `import { IStorageService } from 'ngstorage'`

   `import { IStorageService } from 'angular.storage'`

   or just directly refer to IStorageService like so:

   `angular.storage.IStorageService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), and it's a way to add definitions to existing modules.
In this case, when you are importing the file that you posted it will add the new definitions to the `angular` module, just like the js file does at runtime.

You should be able to import it like so:

```
import * as angular from 'ngstorage';

let a: angular.storage.IStorageService;
...
```

---

#### Edit

Try:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import 'ngstorage';

let a: angular.storage.IStorageService;
```

Comment: What's the significance of using the export keyword inside the module? Wouldn't just declaring the namespace add it to the module and make it available? Also, using `angular.storage.IStorageService` gives me the error "error TS2305: Module 'angular' has no exported member 'storage'."

Comment: Where did you get the `.d.ts` file from?

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/ngstorage/index.d.ts . Installed via npm @types/ngstorage